# SQL - Multiple where in clause from the same subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to do do multiple selects from the same subquery?  Here is an example query I would like to build, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it (I realize the query doesn't work, I just wrote it to communicate what I'm trying to do):

```
SELECT 
    (SUM(my_column) FROM stats WHERE condition = 404 AND my_id IN (t) as total), 
    (SUM(my_column) FROM stats WHERE condition = 404 AND condition2 <> 404 AND my_id IN (t) as total2), 
    SELECT my_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id AS my_id
        FROM stats
        JOIN my_object ON stats.my_id = my_object.id
        WHERE stats.condition = 404 
        AND my_object.created_at >= '2013-08-03 04:00:00.000000' AND my_object.created_at IS NOT NULL
        AND condition2 <> 404 GROUP BY my_id
    ) AS t
```

I'm working in postgres, but would prefer an ANSI SQL solution.

Resulting data:

```
id  total total2
1   5     NULL
2   NULL  6
3   6     9
4   1     1235
```

Thanks!

Comment: Better than a sample query that doesn't work (and doesn't make sense at least to me) would be sample data and the results you want to accomplish.  Your outer query has no `from` clause; you have the construct `my_id in (t)`, and you have a what looks like a subquery but there are no parentheses around it.

Comment: Yea I realize it doesn't work... The idea is that the first 2 selects would get data from a subquery that is JUST the id column, does that makes sense? I don't know the proper syntax to write the subquery (which is why i'm asking the question)

Comment: Why is the subquery just the ID column?

Comment: Because for the 2 sums in the first select, I just need to do a where in (the ids).  I can't do a join as the where clauses on the 2 summations are too different (and can vary more).

Comment: The subquery has to return my_column and condition for you to be able to use those. Try using a CASE statement for the two "WHERE"s.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to test, because you gave only result data and not input data, and also you've not used aliases in your query so it's not possible to be sure about your schema, but you can use something like this:

```
select
    s.my_id,
    sum(s.my_column) as total, 
    sum(case when s.condition2 <> 404 then s.my_column else 0 end) as total2 
from stats as s
    inner join my_object as o on o.id = s.my_id
where
    s.condition = 404 and
    o.created_at >= '2013-08-03 04:00:00' and
    o.created_at is not null
group by s.my_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make a few changes to the position of the aliases in your correlated subqueries, but I think other than that what you have done should work.

I have reworked your query:

```
SELECT * from
    (
    (select SUM(my_column) FROM stats WHERE condition = 404 AND my_id IN (t)) as total, 
    (select SUM(my_column) FROM stats WHERE condition = 404 AND condition2  404 AND my_id IN (t)) as total2, 
    (SELECT my_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id 
        FROM stats
        JOIN my_object ON stats.my_id = my_object.id
        WHERE stats.condition = 404 
        AND my_object.created_at >= '2013-08-03 04:00:00.000000' AND my_object.created_at IS NOT NULL
        AND condition2  404 GROUP BY my_id
    ) AS t) as my_id
    ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need subqueries?

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    SUM(my_column),
    SUM(CASE WHEN condition2 <> 404 THEN my_column ELSE 0 END)
FROM stats
JOIN my_object 
    ON stats.my_id = my_object.id
WHERE stats.condition = 404 
AND my_object.created_at >= '2013-08-03 04:00:00.000000' 
AND my_object.created_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write the outer query:

```
SELECT 
my_id AS id,
SUM(CASE WHEN condition = 404 AND my_id IN (t) THEN my_column ELSE 0 END) AS total,
THEN my_column ELSE 0 END) AS total,
SUM(CASE WHEN condition = 404 AND condition2 <> 404 AND my_id IN (t) 
THEN my_column ELSE 0 END) AS total2
FROM (
    SELECT my_id, condition, condition2, etc.
    ...
) AS subqry
GROUP BY my_id
```

The inner query returns all the columns that you need, and the outer would filter it.